# C++ What's wrong with this simple class?

Tags: c++, class

Just learning Classes in C++, I thought I had a fairly good grip on it but for some reason this code won't even compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Position
{
    int row;
    int column;
public:
    Position();         //constructor
    ~Position();        //destructor
    void setPos(int, int);  //set the position
    int getRow();       //return the current row
    int getColumn();    //return the current column
    void getPos();      //print the pos
    bool compare(int, int); //compare a row and column with the one in the class
};

Position::Position()
{}
Position::~Position()
{}
void Position::setPos(int x, int y)
{
    Position.row = x;
    Position.column = y;
}
int Position::getRow()
{
    return Position.row;
}
int Position::getColumn()
{
    return Position.column;
}
void Position::getPos()
{
    cout << "Row: " << Position.row << "Column: " << Position.column;
}
bool Position::compare(int x, int y)
{
    if(x == Position.row && y == Position.column)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Running this code straight in MS Visual Studio 2010 yields these compiling problems:

`...prob2.cpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'`
Line 30 is: `Position.row = x;`
I don't see why or where there should be a `;` anywhere there.

I get this error on several other lines including the one right under it.

I should note that I don't have a main function although I don't think this is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to prefix instance variables using the class name, instead use `row` or `this->row`

EDIT:

Eventually you will want to move the class declaration to a header file ie. `position.h` and keep the implementation in the `position.cpp` file with `#include "position.h"` at the top.  This will make your Position class usable in other files.

Comment: That's a `.cpp` file. So it's fine :)

Comment: Hm, I distinctly remember prefixing my variables in my other program and it worked. Oh well, it works now, thanks!

Comment: nevermind, I actually didn't prefix my variable in my other program